How to Optimize a Deeply Nested Object Search for Performance?
I have a deeply nested JavaScript object structure representing a hierarchical data model. The object can have multiple levels of nested children, and I need to search for a specific value within this structure. Here is an example of such a nested object:
 const data = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Root",
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Child 1",
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Grandchild 1",
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Grandchild 2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Child 2",
      children: [
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Grandchild 3",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

Currently, I’m using a recursive function to search for the value by ID:
 function searchById(node, id) {
  if (node.id === id) {
    return node;
  }
  if (node.children) {
    for (let child of node.children) {
      const result = searchById(child, id);
      if (result) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const result = searchById(data, 4);
console.log(result);


If you only need to search once, then performance shouldn't be an issue.
If you need to search the same nested object many times, then create another object that maps every id to the result. You can populate that second object in one sweep, and then all searches can be done via the second object.
In the below implementation the generator function getEntriesRecursive yields all [id, node] pairs that are found in the nested data structure. The caller can turn these pairs into an object whose keys are those id, and then the lookup is just a property access:


function* getEntriesRecursive(node) {
    yield [node.id, node];
    for (const child of node.children) {
        yield* getEntriesRecursive(child);
    }
}

// Demo
const data = {id: 1,name: "Root",children: [{id: 2,name: "Child 1",children: [{id: 3,name: "Grandchild 1",children: []},{id: 4,name: "Grandchild 2",children: []}]},{id: 5,name: "Child 2",children: [{id: 6,name: "Grandchild 3",children: []}]}]};
const byId = Object.fromEntries(getEntriesRecursive(data));

for (const id of [4, 6, 5]) {
    console.log(id, byId[id]);
}




For maximum speed when looking for more than 1 item, load them into a map (otherwise your solution is ok):


const data = {id: 1,name: "Root",children: [{id: 2,name: "Child 1",children: [{id: 3,name: "Grandchild 1",children: []},{id: 4,name: "Grandchild 2",children: []}]},{id: 5,name: "Child 2",children: [{id: 6,name: "Grandchild 3",children: []}]}]};

const map = new Map;
const traverse = item => (map.set(item.id, item), item.children?.forEach(traverse));

traverse(data);

for (const id of [4, 6, 5]) {
    console.log(id, map.get(id));
}



A benchmark:
` Chrome/124
--------------------------------------------------
Alexander;  ■ 1.00x | x1000000 155 163 164 164 177
trincot      12.32x |  x100000 191 201 209 212 218
-------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const data = {id: 1,name: "Root",children: [{id: 2,name: "Child 1",children: [{id: 3,name: "Grandchild 1",children: []},{id: 4,name: "Grandchild 2",children: []}]},{id: 5,name: "Child 2",children: [{id: 6,name: "Grandchild 3",children: []}]}]};

// @benchmark Alexander;
const map = new Map;
const traverse = item => (map.set(item.id, item), item.children?.forEach(traverse));

traverse(data);

[4, 6, 5].map(id => map.get(id));

// @benchmark trincot
function* getEntriesRecursive(node) {
  yield [node.id, node];
  for (const child of node.children) {
      yield* getEntriesRecursive(child);
  }
}

const byId = Object.fromEntries(getEntriesRecursive(data));
[4, 6, 5].map(id => byId[id]);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




I appreciate the work that went into this answer. I think the benchmark could be improved if you compare the two algorithms on data sizes practical sizes like n=100, n=1000, and n=10000. Only showing n=3 is only slightly better than no benchmark at all. Fwiw, the benchmark is going to favour your program by a lot :D

@Mulan yes, the benchmark can run several sizes, but on flat arrays, seems i need to add support to nested structures, but there should be different levels of nesting to benchmark, a complex stuff to implement... anyway thanks for an idea

@Mulan anyway the benchmark is pretty valid, since it loops thousands times, and time complexity is O(n) i guess, and it properly demonstrates that generators are slow:  https://dev.to/alexander-nenashev/avoid-iteratorsgenerators-in-javascript-116n
